# Undo actions in a Listview - onitemclicklistener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

this is my code; basically, it is a listview with multiple choice that add a number to a score (textview) when its clicked. My problem is that i would like the number be added to the score when the item is selected in the listview, and removed when the item is deselected. With my code each time that you click an item, the number is added to the score.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView myList;
TextView tv1;

String[] listContent = {

        "Add 2 to total",
        "Add 3 to total",
        "Add 1 to total",
        "Add 5 to total",


};

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final int[] counter = {0};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listContent);
    myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    myList.setAdapter(adapter);


    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        private String[] listview_array2 = {"2", "3", "1", "5"};

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

            if (myList.isItemChecked(position)) {
                String name = this.listview_array2[position];
                int counter2 = Integer.parseInt(name);
                counter[0] = counter[0] + counter2;
                tv1.setText("Total " + counter[0]);


            } else {
            }
        }

    });

}

}
```

I have thought that maybe changing to setOnItemSelected instead of ItemClicked, but I am not sure.

Hope I have explain myself properly and you can help me.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) with a *Boolean* for selection/deselection.

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through your code.
Maintain a flag in the list of your values like List list;

Values is a model containing the number and a flag.

If a item is clicked, set the flag true and do your calculations.

If already clicked item is clicked again, you just need to check the flag.

if(list.getposition(position).isItemClickd){

```
// Decrease that value from total
// list.getposition(position).isItemClickd = false;
```

} else{

```
// list.getposition(position).isItemClickd = true;
// total = total+prevValue;
```

}

Comment: Thank you, but i dont understand it. I have very limited knowledge, I have try to look information about that but I still dont get it, could you insert that inside the code??

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it in a easy way!!!

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

            if (myList.isItemChecked(position)) {
                String name = this.listview_array2[position];
                int counter2 = Integer.parseInt(name);
                counter[0] = counter[0] + counter2;
                tv1.setText("Total " + counter[0]);
```

I add in "else" the same action than in "if", but subtracting the number